# Returning an array of objects that properly defines the SDK response

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have a typical RESTful endpoint that returns a collection of models, but the generated Ruby SDK returns a new model, `Matters` instead of an array of models. I can hack at the generated source code to return `Array<Matter>` but that is a maintenance headache. How do I specify that I want to return `Array<Matter>` in the YAML?

```
paths:
  /matters:
    get:
    ...
    responses:
      200:
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Matters"
...
definitions:
  Matter:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "string"
        description: "Database identifier of the object."
      caseId:
        type: "string"
        description: "Database identifier of the Case object."
      clientMatterNumber:
        type: "string"
        description: "Client/matter billing code."
      judge:
        type: "string"
        description: "Initials of the presiding judge."
      caseNumber:
        type: "string"
        description: "Canonical case number."
      caseTitle:
        type: "string"
        description: "Canonical case title."
      natureOfSuit:
        type: "string"
        description: "Judicial Conference designation of the case."
      docketEntries:
        type: "integer"
        description: "The count of docket entries in the case."
      activityAt:
        type: "string"
        format: "date-time"
        description: "The time of last activity in the case. "
  Matters:
    description: "A collection of matters"
    type: "array"
    items:
      $ref: "#/definitions/Matter"
```

Comment: How do you generate the Ruby SDK - using Swagger Codegen or something else?

Comment: Btw, the property definitions in the `Matter` model are not valid. Paste your spec into http://editor.swagger.io and fix the errors.

Comment: Helen, yes, codegen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
  responses:
    200:
      description: "200 response"
      schema: 
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Matter"
```

Comment: Just to clarify - the solution is to use an inline array model instead of defining the array in `definitions`, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely.