# how to define nested array object in swagger 2.0

Tags: arrays, nested, swagger, swagger-2.0, ref

I try to define an object array in swagger as response:

  `/product:
    get:
      operationId: api.product.read_all
      tags:
        - Product
      summary: Read the Products
      description: Read the Products
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successfully read product set operation
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/definitions/product'`

But I find errors for those:

```
Schema error at paths['/product'].get.responses['200']
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: description, schema
Jump to line 138
Schema error at paths['/product'].get.responses['200'].schema
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: items
Jump to line 140
Schema error at paths['/product'].get.responses['200'].schema
should match exactly one schema in oneOf
Jump to line 140
Schema error at paths['/product'].get.responses['200'].schema.type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: file
Jump to line 141
Schema error at paths['/product'].get.responses['200'].schema.items
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: anyOf
Jump to line 142
Schema error at paths['/product'].get.responses['200'].schema.items
should be array
Jump to line 142
Schema error at paths['/product'].get.responses['200'].schema.items
should match some schema in anyOf
Jump to line 142
```

I know I can use nested array with object like:

```
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          properties:
            id:
              type: string
              description: Id of the cat
            name:
              type: string
              description: category name
```

But I wan to apply the internal array object ref to some objects I already defined. Can swagger do that, how to do that?

I use swagger 2.0

Comment: Just to clarify - do you need an array of `$ref`? Or an array of arrays of `$ref`? Or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning an array of objects that properly defines the SDK response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175188/returning-an-array-of-objects-that-properly-defines-the-sdk-response) and [Return an array of object in SwaggerHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46167981/113116)

Comment: array of $ref. thanks

Comment: Please see the ^^ linked Q&As.